# Ubuntu 20.04 Physical display position does not saved after switching display mode

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, display

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on Lenovo laptop with Lenovo dock station and external monitor. Dock station has built in video card which provides additional video output ports. Most of the time I use external monitor which is physically positioned on the left from laptop - so I configure this in display physical setup as shown below:

[image: Display Mode - Join Displays - Physical display setup]

Some times I need to switch to single display mode, and each time I do this and then switch back to Join Displays mode physical displays position reverts to display 2 being on the right, like that:

[image: Display Mode - Join Displays - Physical display setup]

Is there a way to save my physical display setup so that it persist through display mode switching?